# I want to prove some properties about list, but am stuck at induction

Tags: coq

I tried following proof,

```
Require Import List Omega.
Import ListNotations.
Variable X : Type.

Lemma length_n_nth_app_error_same : forall (n:nat) (x:X) (l:list X),
n <= length l -> 0 < n -> nth_error l n = nth_error (l ++ [x]) n .
Proof.
  intros.
  induction l eqn:eqHl.
  - unfold length in H. omega.
  -
```

but I'm stuck, as what I have is only

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
x : X
l : list X
a : X
l0 : list X
eqHl : l = a :: l0
H : n <= length (a :: l0)
H0 : 0 < n
IHl0 : l = l0 ->
       n <= length l0 ->
       nth_error l0 n = nth_error (l0 ++ [x]) n
______________________________________(1/1)
nth_error (a :: l0) n = nth_error ((a :: l0) ++ [x]) n
```

I've met some similar cases also for other proofs on lists.
I don't know if the usual induction would be useful here.

How should I prove this?
Should I use generalize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theorem is wrong. Maybe your understanding of `nth_error` is incorrect.

Specifically, when `n = length l`, `nth_error l n` returns `None` while `nth_error (l ++ [x]) n` returns `Some x`.

```
Require Import List Omega.
Import ListNotations.

Lemma length_n_nth_app_error_not_always_same :
  (forall (n:nat) (X:Type) (x:X) (l:list X),
  n <= length l -> 0 < n -> nth_error l n = nth_error (l ++ [x]) n)
  -> False.
Proof.
  intros.
  assert (1 <= 1) by omega. assert (0 < 1) by omega.
  specialize (H 1 nat 2 [1] H0 H1). simpl in H. inversion H. Qed.
```

On the other hand, proving a similar theorem with fixed inequality is easy:

```
Lemma length_n_nth_app_error_same : forall (n:nat) (X:Type) (x:X) (l:list X),
n < length l -> nth_error l n = nth_error (l ++ [x]) n .
Proof.
  induction n; intros.
  - simpl. destruct l; simpl in *.
    + omega.
    + reflexivity.
  - simpl. destruct l; simpl in *.
    + omega.
    + apply IHn. omega. Qed.
```

Note that I used `induction n` instead of `induction l`. It is mainly because `nth_error` does recursive calls on decreasing `n`.

Also, if you felt like an induction hypothesis is not general enough, it is probably because your order of `intros` and `induction` was wrong. The rule of thumb is to start the proof by `induction`, and then `intros` the variables. If it is still not enough, you can `revert dependent` all the variables other than the one to do induction, and then `induction x; intros`.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you for the reply. It helped not only on the specific issue, but my understanding in general.